# Drawable not beign fond in kotlin file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to access a drawable resource from a non Activity class, this is because I want to have my composable function in another file rather than having it in the main file, the thing is that from the Main file I can access `R.drawable.header` , but from the other crated file I cant

[image]

```
import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.Text
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumnFor
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.imageResource
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.jetexample.ui.typography

@Composable
fun RecipeCard(recipe: Recipe){
    val image = imageResource(R.drawable.header)
    Surface(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),elevation = 8.dp,modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
            val imageModifier = Modifier.preferredHeight(150.dp).fillMaxWidth().clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            Image(asset = image,modifier = imageModifier,contentScale = ContentScale.Crop)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.preferredHeight(16.dp))
            Text(text = recipe.title,style = typography.h6)
            for(ingredient in recipe.ingredients){
                Text(text = ingredient,style = typography.body2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know it has something to do with the context, thats why I cant access the resource I think, but I have tried with ContextAmbient and I still cant

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if `R.drawable` points to the drawable resource folder in your project. As I see you have not imported resources in your file.

```kotlin
import com.example.jetexample.R
```